# How to create variable names in a function with paste

Tags: r, function, paste

I am trying to create a variable inside a function in R, but the name of this variable depends on the parameter of the function, so I want to name it with paste.

I will show what I mean with an example:

```
variable <- function(name){
assign(paste0("variable_",name),1)
}
variable("one")
variable_one
```

How should I use the `assign` command so I can access the variable outside the function? What I mean is that when I use `variable_one` I get `1` (I know using `<<-` , but not with `assign`).
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To change variables outside of the function you need to specify the `envir` argument to `assign`.

This will lead to the desired result in your case.

```
variable <- function(name) {
    assign(paste0("variable_", name), 1, envir = parent.frame())
}
```

However it is almost always better to use a different solution such as what Ronak Shah suggests, as things can get messy quickly if you fiddle too much with things like these.

Consider (using the above function):

```
variable_two <- "twenty"
variable("two")
```

This will overwrite `variable_two` without a warning, potentially leading to problems further down the line.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to use `assign`?

Instead of cluttering your environment with global variables you could return them as `list`

```
variable <- function(name){
   setNames(list(1), paste0("variable_", name))
}

variable("two")
#$variable_two
#[1] 1
```

If you want to make it more general, you could do

```
variable <- function(name){
   setNames(as.list(rep(1, length(name))), paste0("variable_", name))
}

lst1 <- variable(c("two", "three"))
```

and then access individual values using `[[`

```
lst1[["variable_two"]]
#[1] 1
lst1[["variable_three"]]
#[1] 1
```